# how to remove punctuation from a txt file without changing the format

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with 1000 rows and 2 columns. I want to remove all punctuation and convert all cases to lower case of that file and want a output file with same format like 1000 rows and 2 columns.
I am running the following code:

```
import re
original_string = open('Suppliers0403.csv').read()
middle_string=original_string.lower()
new_string = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9\n\.]+', ' ', middle_string)
open('sup.csv', 'w').write(new_string)
```

I am getting the output but the output file is scattered. Its coming as a single column.
I have the file like this:

```
 id       col1
  1        a
  2        ??
  3        b"v"
  4        "c"an
  5        ?
```

the output is coming like:

```
idcol1
1a
2
3bv
4can
5
```

But I want it like:

```
id     col1
1        a
2
3        bv
4        can
5
```

Comment: Your output is likely to be inaccurate; either you didn't include the spaces your `re.sub()` introduces, or you are using an empty string as the replacement in the `re.sub()` call. Your input sample should come out as `1 a`, `2`, `3 b v` *at the very least*, ignoring the fact that your sample input has spaces at the start of the lines.

Answer (score 5):

You have a tab-separated file and are replacing the tabs; you'd need to adjust your regular expression to:

```
'[^a-z0-9\n\.\t]+'
```

(With `A-Z` removed as you are lowercasing the input already anyway).

A more robust and generic method would be to use the `csv` module to preserve the format:

```
input_filename = 'Suppliers0403.csv'
output_filename = 'sup.csv'
clean = re.compile(r'[^a-z0-9\.]+')

with open(input_filename, 'rb') as infh, open(output_filename, 'wb') as outfh:
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(infh.read(1024))
    infh.seek(0)
    reader = csv.reader(infh, dialect)
    writer = csv.writer(outfh, dialect)

    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow([clean.sub(' ', c.lower()) for c in row])
```

Comment: Is there any way to remove the leading and lagging space of the field values.

Comment: @user3231684: Use `c.strip().lower()` instead of just `c.lower()`.

Comment: I am running the code but its giving an error:                            Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/python_folder/python0403/punc_0503.py", line 7, in <module>
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(infh.read(1024))
NameError: name 'csv' is not defined